# How i can use cloud mysql database with java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee, crm

I Have a software built in Java/Swing mysql. Can I use any Cloud Service for storing and retrieving data with JDBC? or what else i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several SQL-in-the-cloud options, including **[Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/)** and **[Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)** both of which offer MySQL.   Once set up, you can connect to them using JDBC like any other MySQL database.

Comment: simple JDBC will do ? or requires some more coding And my software is not using any web component.. Sorry I don't have even a bit of experience for cloud databases.

Comment: Simple JDBC will do.  Whichever provider you go with, their online admin tools and documentation will help you work out the connection parameters you need (including authentication).  Probably best to start by following a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

***Check following code for ref.***

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty" %>

<html>
  <body>

<%
String url = null;
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
    SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
  // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver"); 
  url = "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/guestbook?user=root";
} else {
  // Local MySQL instance to use during development.
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root";
}

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(
    "SELECT guestName, content, entryID FROM entries");
%>

<table style="border: 1px solid black">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="35%" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Name</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Message</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">ID</th>
</tr>

<%
while (rs.next()) {
    String guestName = rs.getString("guestName");
    String content = rs.getString("content");
    int id = rs.getInt("entryID");
 %>
<tr>
<td><%= guestName %></td>
<td><%= content %></td>
<td><%= id %></td>
</tr>
<%
}
conn.close();
%>

</tbody>
</table>


  </body>
</html>
```